# Bar dashed chart is overlapping in chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, chart.js

I have data and I am creating a stacked bar chart, I want one of the datasets to be a dashed bar chart.

The live: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kox9g38m/2/)

Here is what I have done so far.

HTML.

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

And Js.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Employee',
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58,12, 59, 87, 45],
      borderColor:"#45c490",
      borderWidth: 0
        }, {
            label: 'Engineer',
            backgroundColor: "orange",
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58,12, 59, 85, 23],
      borderColor:"#caf270",
      borderWidth: 0
        }, {
            label: 'Government',
            backgroundColor: "pink",
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58,12, 59, 65, 51],
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 0
        }, {
            label: 'Political parties',
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58, 12, 59, 12, 74],
      borderColor:"#caf270",
      borderWidth: 0
        }],
    },
options: {
    tooltips: {
      displayColors: true,
      callbacks:{
        mode: 'x',
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        type: 'linear',
      }]
    },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
   
    },
  plugins: [{
    afterDatasetDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
       args.meta.data.forEach(function(element) {
         var borderWidth = 3;
         var ctx = chart.ctx;
         var vm = element._view;
         var half = vm.width / 2;
         var left = vm.x - half;
         var right = vm.x + half;
         var top = vm.y;
         var width = right - left;
         var height = chart.chartArea.bottom - top + (borderWidth / 2) - 1;
         let label = vm.datasetLabel;
         if(label.includes("Government")){
          ctx.setLineDash([5,5]);
          borderWidth=1;
         }else{
          ctx.setLineDash([0,0]);
          borderWidth=1
         }
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
         ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
         ctx.moveTo(left, top);
         ctx.lineTo(left, top + height);
         ctx.moveTo(left, top);
         ctx.lineTo(left + width, top);
         ctx.moveTo(left + width, top);
         ctx.lineTo(left + width, top + height);
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.save();
   });
     }
   }]
});
```

I want only if the dataset label is Government then create the dashed bar otherwise just normal

The problem
[image]

In the picture above you can see the government dataset has dashed and the blue border.

How can I eliminate this blue border here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should be in the height calculation because the plugin was thought for no-stacked bar.:

```
var height = chart.chartArea.bottom - top + (borderWidth / 2) - 1;
```

As you can see, the `height` is calculated assuming to go to the bottom of chart area.
You can try the following, overriding the above row:

```
const valueTop = element._yScale.getValueForPixel(top);
const value = chart.data.datasets[element._datasetIndex].data[element._index];
const bottom = element._yScale.getPixelForValue(valueTop - value);
var height = bottom - top + (borderWidth / 2) - 1;
```